# customized collapsable qtool button in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using a customized collapsable qtool button class in pyqt5 in order to make a drop down tool bar which will expand and collapse.The qtool button will have qpushbutton as its items.When a user will click the qtoolbutton the qpushbutton will be displayed.

The problem i am having is that when a collapsable tool button has qtool button as it items, the child qtool button items overlaps with the buttons of the parent qtool button as a result they cannot be properly displayed in the layout.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class CollapsibleBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, title="", parent=None):
        super(CollapsibleBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.toggle_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text=title, checkable=True, checked=False)
        self.toggle_button.setStyleSheet("QToolButton {background-color:#dadada;}")
        self.toggle_button.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.ArrowType.RightArrow)
        self.toggle_button.pressed.connect(self.on_pressed)

        self.toggle_animation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(self)

        self.content_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(maximumHeight=0, minimumHeight=0)
        self.content_area.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.content_area.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.toggle_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.content_area)

        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight"))
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight"))
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.content_area, b"maximumHeight"))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pressed(self):
        checked = self.toggle_button.isChecked()
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.ArrowType.DownArrow if not checked else QtCore.Qt.ArrowType.RightArrow)
        self.toggle_animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward if not checked else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
        self.toggle_animation.start()

    def setContentLayout(self, layout):
        lay = self.content_area.layout()
        del lay
        self.content_area.setLayout(layout)
        collapsed_height = self.sizeHint().height() - self.content_area.maximumHeight()
        content_height = layout.sizeHint().height()
        for i in range(self.toggle_animation.animationCount()):
            animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(i)
            animation.setDuration(500)
            animation.setStartValue(collapsed_height)
            animation.setEndValue(collapsed_height + content_height)

        content_animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(self.toggle_animation.animationCount() - 1)
        content_animation.setDuration(500)
        content_animation.setStartValue(0)
        content_animation.setEndValue(content_height)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import random

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    w.setCentralWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget())
    dock = QtWidgets.QDockWidget("Collapsible Demo")
    w.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, dock)
    scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
    dock.setWidget(scroll)
    content = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    content.setStyleSheet("background-color:white")
    scroll.setWidget(content)
    scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
    vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(content)

    towerGeometry = CollapsibleBox("Tower Geometry")

    vlay.addWidget(towerGeometry)
    layoutForTowerGeometry = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    section = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Sections")


    section.setStyleSheet("background-color: #dadada ;")
    layoutForTowerGeometry.addWidget(section)
    towerGeometry.setContentLayout(layoutForTowerGeometry)


    #Header for Input

    flanges = CollapsibleBox("Flanges")
    layoutForGeometryParameters = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    geometryParameters = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Geometry Parameters")


    geometryParameters.setStyleSheet("background-color: #dadada ;")
    layoutForGeometryParameters.addWidget(geometryParameters)
    flanges.setContentLayout(layoutForGeometryParameters)



    guidanceInfo = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Guidance Info")


    guidanceInfo.setStyleSheet("background-color: #dadada ;")
    layoutForGeometryParameters.addWidget(guidanceInfo)
    flanges.setContentLayout(layoutForGeometryParameters)
    layoutForTowerGeometry.addWidget(flanges)
    towerGeometry.setContentLayout(layoutForTowerGeometry)

    cans = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Cans")


    cans.setStyleSheet("background-color: #dadada ;")
    layoutForTowerGeometry.addWidget(cans)
    towerGeometry.setContentLayout(layoutForTowerGeometry)

    vlay.addStretch()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The code that you provide does not generate the problem that you point out, besides it is obvious that the code that does not generate the image since at least the sentences are different

Comment: Please reduce the code example so that only the essential part for the problem remains. Produce a [example].

Answer (score 0):

When you set the layout, you set also the maximum height of the widget based on the size of its content. But, it will not grow or shrink if its content is resized. Especially when you expand the second box.

Don't modify the size of your widget directly. Create a new class which will manages the content and let you change its size:

A simple example:

```
class Container(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.expanded = False
        self.setFixedHeight(0)

    def setExpand(self, expanded):
        self.expanded = expanded
        if expanded:
            self.setMinimumHeight(0)
            self.setMaximumHeight(0)
        else:
            self.setMinimumHeight(self.sizeHint().height())
            self.setMaximumHeight(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX)

class CollapsibleBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, title="", parent=None):
        super(CollapsibleBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.toggle_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text=title, checkable=True, checked=False)
        self.toggle_button.setStyleSheet("QToolButton {background-color:#dadada;}")
        self.toggle_button.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)
        self.toggle_button.pressed.connect(self.on_pressed)

        self.toggle_animation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(self)

        self.content_area = Container()

        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.lay.setSpacing(0)
        self.lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.toggle_button)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.content_area)
        self.lay.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pressed(self):
        self.adjustSize()
        self.content_area.setExpand(self.toggle_button.isChecked())

    def setContentLayout(self, layout):
        l = self.content_area.layout()
        del l
        self.content_area.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: the solution that you have provided outputs the following gui [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/tZMeCO8) where there is always a space between child qtool button with its parent child qpushbottons and this space does not adjust when the child qtool button collapses

Comment: My solution is just base and should be improved. But, this behavior is due to the way the layouts work. If you add the line `layoutForTowerGeometry.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)` in you main part, you will not see this empty space.